# Was Thor trying to help or hinder Stark and Banner's plan?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

This whole question is a spoiler:

> When Thor appeared at Tony Stark’s lab when they were trying to revive The Vision while in the cradle, he hit it with Mjolnir's lightning

Was Thor's intention to destroy it, or did he learn some information after

> going to the cave and itend Mjolnir to revive The Vision?

Answer (score 7):

Thor did *not* want to destroy it, Here is why he did it:

> 1. Just after Vision is born, Steve asks Thor if he "Helped create this?". Thor replies with an affirmative tone that this had connections with the vision he saw in the Water of Sight.
>  2. When Thor is first enchanted by Scarlet Witch, he has a hallucination. In the Hallucination, Heimdall holds him, and then suddenly the screen turns white. Thor sees an image of the 6 infinity stones, & of Vision opening his eyes. This is the exact scene from the trailer, just displayed for a mere split second.
>  3. Thor & the rest of the team did not want the Infinity stone to touch the surface. This is confirmed when the Avengers are trying to get hold of the Cradle, & Steve tells them over the radio comm that "The stone should not touch the surface or it will wipe out the entire city". Thor could have shared the same fear, thus letting the Stone get integrated into Vision.

Comment: Sounds right to me, although I think it’s just the stone from Guardians (the Power Stone?) that can’ touch the earth. The Tesseract and the Aether pretty much touched the earth without incident.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite it's strongly implied, and IIRC explicity shown in *Age of Ultron*, that the objects we've been seeing (Tesseract, Scepter, etc) are merely *containers* for Infinity Stones.. even the Aether is not the "real" form of the stone. It's not clear what would happen if someone tried to bust open the Tesseract and take the stone inside it.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: sure, yeah that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think judging by what happened before and afterwards, we can conclude that Thor was actually trying to

> give life to The Vision, and imbue that life with some aspect of Thor himself.

Before Thor jumped in, Stark and Banner were attempting to

> insert J.A.R.V.I.S. into the body in the cradle, so that he would control it, and not Ultron.

However,

> Quicksilver disconnected most of the wires from the cradle, which seemed to interrupt this process, potentially dangerously.

After Thor’s intervention

> Thor explains that he learned from the cave that the being in the cradle had an Infinity Stone in it, and that it was important that the being could keep the stone safe from Ultron. Presumably, he was therefore trying to make the being into someone who would do so.

When we see

> The Vision, not only does he imitate Thor’s clothes, but he is able to wield Mjolnir. This suggests Thor managed to put a bit of himself into The Vision.

Comment: I do not think Vision imitated Thor. Thor used the lightening as a power source for the cradle, so that the Vision could be born. Apart from the cape, his "clothes" are not really all that similar to Thors. He did not intend to imbue Vision with some aspect of himself, or else he would not have been surprised when Vision lifted the hammer.

Comment: @ash_k29: ah sure. That’s a good point — the lightning is just to power the cradle.